# Multiple tsconfigs for multiple folders

Tags: typescript, typechecking, tsconfig, tsc

I have a Next.js project with TypeScript. My E2E tests are written with Cypress. I need to tell `tsc` how to deal with multiple configs. It needs to handle different configs for different folders.

Next.js' `tsconfig.json` in the project root is this.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Cypress has its own `cypress/tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"],
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have a `"type-check"` script.

```json
"type-check": "tsc --pretty --noEmit"
```

Running this script fails because it tries to compile the Cypress folder using the project root's config. How can I write this type check command, so it uses the right `tsconfig.json` for each folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is to have your `type-check` script run tsc twice, once for your nextjs files, and once for your cypress files:

```json
"type-check": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit && tsc -p cypress/tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit"
```

You would also need to amend the nextjs `tsconfig.json` to exclude files in the cypress folder:

```json
"exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"],
```

(this is probably a good idea in any case - your next app doesn't need to fail compilation if there's an error in your cypress files).